How to reverse the order of a Powershell ordered hashtable / dictionary
I want to achive a simple goal. Stop some services in a defined order on multiple servers and afterwards start them in the reversed order.
So first step is to define an ordered hashtable / dictonary.
$serviceServer = [ordered]@{
    "service3" = @("server1")
    "service1" = @("server2", "server3")
    "service2" = @("server1", "server2", "server3")
}

But how do I reverse the order for the restart of the services?
In php I would do an array_reverse ... no big deal, but Powershell seems to have its own meaning of easiness.
I tried Sort-Object in multiple ways, but the order stay the same.
$reverseServices = $serviceServer | Sort-Object


Look at this and try at your own, i have done some performance tests.
$serviceServers = [ordered]@{
    "service3" = @("server1")
    "service1" = @("server2", "server3")
    "service2" = @("server1", "server2", "server3")
    "service6" = @("server1")
    "service4" = @("server2", "server3")
    "service5" = @("server1", "server2", "server3")
    "service9" = @("server1")
    "service7" = @("server2", "server3")
    "service8" = @("server1", "server2", "server3")
}

function Reverse-ByEnum1 {
    param(
        $serviceServer
    )
    $keys = @($serviceServer.Keys)
    $serviceServer.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object { $keys.IndexOf($_.Key) } -Descending
}

function Reverse-ByEnum2 {
    param(
        $serviceServer
    )
    $serviceServer.GetEnumerator() `
        | foreach-object `
            -begin   { $r = [ordered] @{} } `
            -process { $r.Insert(0, $_.Key, $_.Value) } `
            -end     { $r }
}

function Reverse-ByKeys {
    param(
        $serviceServer
    )
    $reversedServiceServer = [ordered] @{}
    foreach ($key in $serviceServer.Keys) {
        $reversedServiceServer.Insert(0, $key, $serviceServer[$key]) 
    }
    $reversedServiceServer
}

Measure-Command {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt 10000; $i++) {
        $reverse1 = Reverse-ByEnum1 $serviceServers
    }
}

Measure-Command {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt 10000; $i++) {
        $reverse2 = Reverse-ByEnum2 $serviceServers
    }
}

Measure-Command {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt 10000; $i++) {
        $reverse3 = Reverse-ByKeys $serviceServers
    }
}

Write-Host =====================================================================
$reverse1
Write-Host =====================================================================
$reverse2
Write-Host =====================================================================
$reverse3


I can’t test right now, so not posting as an answer, but OrderedDictionary has an “Insert” method you could use to iterate over all the existing keys and then “Insert” into a new OrderedDictionary at index zero. This will reverse the order in the new OrderedDictionary and preserve it in your original.

@elh: The tradeoffs by which you can assess the solutions are: Do you need to construct a new ordered hashtable or is enumerating the entries in reverse order sufficient? Does performance matter? Pipeline-based solutions are potentially more concise and elegant, but relatively slow - but with smallish hashtables that won't matter.

I love performance and readability for other people, wich don't have the experience I have. So it might be good to design a key holder for this question. Something like a design pattern. ... And I don't want a resolution that fast. Might be there are some other good ideas for a common problem.

But I want to clarify the quality of your and the other answers. Thank you!

Note that in your benchmarks you not just measuring the performance of the concerned method but also the function call which is rather exspenscive in PowerShell, see PowerShell functions and performance and What is the best way to reuse static code

@iRon good to know, thanks.

Three ideas, one is using IndexOf and -Descending sorting:
$serviceServer = [ordered]@{
    'service3'   = @('server1')
    'service1'   = @('server2', 'server3')
    'service2'   = @('server1', 'server2', 'server3')
    'servicefoo' = @('server1')
}

$keys = @($serviceServer.Keys)
$serviceServer.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object { $keys.IndexOf($_.Key) } -Descending

Second one is using Enumerable.Reverse:
[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Reverse([object[]] $serviceServer.Keys) |
    ForEach-Object { "Service: '$_' - [$($serviceServer[$_])]" }

Third one is by casting to a Stack:
[System.Collections.Stack] $serviceServer

In all cases the original OrderedDictionary is intact but you can create a new one following this logic.

look's quite efficient.

@elh don't think efficiency matters that much for such a small dictionary, I added a third option in my eyes the simplest one using a Stack

@mklement0 Thanks. Didn't think that would work but it does, nice!


To construct a new ordered hashtable with the entries of the original one in reverse order, you can enumerate the keys of the original and insert each new entry at position 0 into the new dictionary, which effectively reverses the original order - this is a non-pipeline alternative to mclayton's helpful answer, from which this clever technique is borrowed:
# Construct a new ordered hashtable with the entries of the original one in
# reverse order.
$reversedServiceServer = [ordered] @{}
foreach ($key in $serviceServer.Keys) {
  $reversedServiceServer.Insert(0, $key, $serviceServer[$key]) 
}
$reversedServiceServer # Print the new hashtable, for visual verification.


If it is sufficient to stream the ordered dictionary's entries in reverse order, using the pipeline:
$i = 0; $serviceServer.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object { (--([ref] $i).Value) }

Update: The [System.Collections.Stack]-based solution in Santiago's helpful answer is a more efficient and elegant alternative (it returns a stack of the original dictionary entries in reverse order; if used in a pipeline, the entries would be auto-enumerated; to explicitly turn the stack into an array, append .ToArray()).

While more concise than the solution at the top, it is decidedly slower (though with small hashtables that won't matter), due to the use of the pipeline in general, and a calculated property (script block) used with Sort-Object in particular.

The Sort-Object call uses an aux. variable that is decremented for each input object and therefore in effect reverses the order of the input objects;[1] ([ref] $i) is a concise way to refer to the $i variable in the parent scope, which is necessary, because calculated properties run in a child scope of the caller.

While the output looks like an ordered hashtable with the entries reversed, it is a stream of [System.Collections.DictionaryEntry] instances, each with a .Key and a .Value property (PowerShell additionally aliases .Key to .Name).



[1] This technique was borrowed from this question.

It seems to be the actually fastest and best understandable way.

Another option that returns a reversed OrderedDictionary, in case that’s a requirement:
$reversed = $serviceServer.GetEnumerator() `
    | foreach-object `
        -begin   { $r = [ordered] @{} } `
        -process { $r.Insert(0, $_.Key, $_.Value) } `
        -end     { $r }

It uses the OrderedDictionary Insert method to iterate over the original collection and insert each item at the start of a new instance, effectively reversing it.

oh my gosh ... it get's more and more efficient.
